# How to log in using pin code instead username and password in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.4.3 and Spring Security spring-security-core:2.0-RC5. I can easily log in with this using username and password. Now there is a requirement that I will have to log in with pin number not username and password.

There will be no username, password field in login form. Now this is the problem. I could not try it because I have no idea how to do it instead of username and password. Here I can share only my login form with username and password field which is working as below:

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
            <div>
                <span><label>Username</label></span>
                <span><input type="text" class="textbox" name='j_username' id="active"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span><label>Password</label></span>
                <span><input type="password" name='j_password' class="password"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="sign">
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type='submit' id="submit" value='${message(code: "springSecurity.login.button")}'/>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Have you got answer for you question? If yes please share that. Also, look at my answer if that solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well everything you want to alter lies in `DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy` under the plugin.

I remember doing this for email Id and had overridden several security configurations.

In order to set j_username form field to different name you may override

> grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.usernameParameter=zipcode //your domain field name

and to change the field which needs to be considered as user name from Domain class by overriding following in security config:

> grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='zipcode'

Remember to dig into `DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy` file for any other such customization.I would suggest creating a separate Security config file and there override any configuration if required.